# Is the converter between docx and pdf files in Sharepoint the same as the one in MS Word

Tags: word-automation, conversion

**The scenario:** I edit a MS Word document via code, and then use Word Automation Services(SyncConverter more precisely) to convert it to pdf. Currently there is a problem on the server and the conversion fails(this will be fixed). Until it is fixed I must send the client an example of the result.

**What I do:** I do my work with the Word document and then save it as a .docx file. No problem there. Then I open the file in MS Word 2013 and save it as .pdf.

**The question:** Will the file I convert manually and the generated one be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed:** After testing both results I was able to confirm that the two files (the generated .pdf and the manually converted .pdf) are indeed identical.

Comment: Could you mark your own post as answer?